# PHP JSON Steam API request and print

Tags: arrays, json, steam

Whats wrong with my code? I wolud like to print like the total_time_played and more details.

```
$url = 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=7BBE9B2D821CEBBC0F4944912BE26DC5&steamid=76561197980138287';
$urljson = file_get_contents('$url');


$data = json_decode($urljson)->playerstats;

$new_array = array();
foreach ($data->stats as $item) {
    $new_array[$item->name] = $item->value;
}
echo $new_array['total_time_played'];
```

Comment: I guess you don't mean that you only print `total_time_played` and you forgot to print any other details, so... what's your problem exactly?

Comment: My total_time_played is 600254 and i would love to print this on my site.

Comment: Please clarify where you are having problem.  What does your current script do that differs from what you expect? What debugging have you done to determine where the script behaves differently than expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are going to try to get contents from literal `'$url'` string, not your string value of `$url` variable.

This:

```
$urljson = file_get_contents('$url');
```

Needs to change to this:

```
$urljson = file_get_contents($url);
```

Note the single quotes (which prevent variable interpolation) have been removed.